# How to replace two substrings with preg_replace?

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-replace-callback

I want to replace two substrings with each other, as

```
$str = 'WORD1 some text WORD2 and we have WORD1.';

$result = 'WORD2 some text WORD1 and we have WORD2.';
```

I use `preg_replace` to match the replacing words,

```
$result = preg_replace('/\bWORD1(?=[\W.])/i', 'WORD2', $str);
```

but, how can I change `WORD2` to `WORD1` (in the original `$str`)?

The problem is that the replacement should be done at the same time. Otherwise, `word1` changed to `word2` will be changed to `word1` again.

How can I make the replacements at the same time?

Comment: `strtr($str, ['WORD1'=>'WORD2', 'WORD2'=>'WORD1']);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$str = 'WORD1 some text WORD2 and we have WORD1.';
echo preg_replace_callback('~\b(?:WORD1|WORD2)\b~', function ($m) {
    return $m[0] === "WORD1" ? "WORD2" : "WORD1";
}, $str);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/DFO3Ex).

If `WORD`s are Unicode strings, also add `u` modifier, `'~\b(?:WORD1|WORD2)\b~u'`.

The `\b(?:WORD1|WORD2)\b` pattern matches either `WORD1` or `WORD2` as whole words, and then, inside the anonymous function used as a replacement argument, you may check the match value and apply custom replacement logic for each case.

Answer (score 1):

Just as another way.

You can Replace step by step if you use a intermediate-char. I prefere the preg_replace_callback() too, just to be shown what i mean:

```
$str = 'WORD1 some text WORD2 and we have WORD1.';

$w1 = "WORD1";
$w2 = "WORD2";

$interChr = chr(0);
$str = str_replace($w1, $interChr, $str);
$str = str_replace($w2, $w1, $str);
$str = str_replace($interChr, $w2, $str);

echo $str;
// WORD2 some text WORD1 and we have WORD2.
```